# Why script freezes on the line print "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG=: ",''.join(diff)

Tags: python, file, for-loop, printing, diff

Script stops at the line `print "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG=: ",''.join(diff)` and no longer goes forward, I can not understand why. `file_path1` and `file_path2` are correct. Even if I remove this line of script still freezes on the line `for line in diff:` What is the problem and how to solve it

```
def is_diff_two_files(file_path1, file_path2):
    with open(file_path1, 'r') as file1:            
        with open(file_path2, 'r') as file2:            
            diff = difflib.unified_diff(file1.readlines(),
                file2.readlines(), fromfile=file_path1, tofile=file_path2, n=0) 
            print "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG=: ", ''.join(diff)           
            for line in diff:                
                diff_str += line
    if diff_str == '':        
        return (0, diff_str)
    else:        
        return (1, diff_str)
```

Comment: How large are the files? How long have you waited? Note that `unified_diff` returns a *generator*, so at the time of the `print` statement, no *actual* work has been done yet.

Comment: script remains in place even after 3 hours, file size 831M.

Comment: That is a ***huge*** file to diff! As you should always do, try your code against a small, simple example to make sure it works. Also, try running the actual `diff` utility (with similar options) against the files, to see how long it should take.

Comment: Remove `print "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG=: ", ''.join(diff)`. Then try add `print(line)` at the next line of `for line in diff`. This may print something.

Comment: Agree @Jonathon Reinhart. Try test a smaller part.

Comment: on small files works perfectly and quickly.

Comment: Voting to close. There's nothing wrong with the code, only in how it's being used.

Comment: Note that, according to the documentation for [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html), the algorithm used is quadratic in the worst case. This means that for a 831M file it could take `(831*10**6)**2 = 690561000000000000` operations (on bytes). If I'm not mistaken a normal computer should take order of 10 years to do all those operations!